# spatie/laravel-medialibrary Google Cloud Storage compatibility

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-storage

I have a Laravel app that uploads pictures to S3 or to local storage.
But I can't upload to GCS.
Is Laravel media library compatible with any GCS library?
I'm asking this because I keep on getting:

"message    "Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::makeDirectory()"
exception   "Error"
file    "/var/www/html/vendor/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/src/MediaCollections/Filesystem.php"
line    317"

When I look at Filesystem, it has createDirectory() instead of makeDirectory().

So is there any library that I can use to upload to GCS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage) .
You can install the package via composer:

composer require spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage